# Errors saving data to Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

We are trying to save streaming data to Google Datastore using this repo as the basis: https://github.com/meraki/google-cloud-scanning-api. After the update to Meraki 3.0, we had to refactor the code to reflect the new data structure. However, we are now getting errors in Cloud Functions during the save process:

```
ERROR SAVING: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24)
at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14) {
code: 4,
metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {}, flags: 0 },
details: 'Deadline Exceeded'
}
```

and

```
ERROR SAVING: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Received RST_STREAM with error code 7
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/workspace/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24)
at callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14) {
code: 14,
metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {}, flags: 0 },
details: 'Received RST_STREAM with error code 7'
}
```

We think this is a rate error. Our metrics show that we went from about 4.7 invocations per second to 0.03 invocations per second. We think we are ingesting more data in shorter bursts, causing it to exceed the rate limits. We tried to implement a retry (pulled from here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#uses_for_transactions) but we still see the error on some saves.

Our retry function:

```
async function addObservationWithRetry(entry, type) {
    const maxTries = 5;
    async function tryRequest(currentAttempt, delay) {
        try {
            await addObservation(entry, type);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Timeout, attempt ${currentAttempt}`);
            if (currentAttempt <= maxTries) {
                // Use exponential backoff
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    await tryRequest(currentAttempt + 1, delay * 2);
                }, delay);
            }
            throw err;
        }
    }
    await tryRequest(1, 100);
}
```

Calling the retry function:

```
observations.forEach(function(entry) {
    addObservationWithRetry(entry, "event");
});
```

Adding an observation:

```
function addObservation(obs, type) {
    let entities = [];
    const locations = obs.locations;
    const entity = {
        key: "null",
        data: [<dictionaries for all variables>],
    };

    locations.forEach(function(loc) {
        entity.data[x].value = <different values that are the same for each location>;

        loc.rssiRecords.forEach(function(record) {
            const observationKey = datastore.key(type);
            entity.key = observationKey;
            entity.data[y].value = <different values that are the same for each rssi record>;
            entities.push(entity);

        });
    });

    if (entities.length > 0) {
        datastore
            .save(entities) // Push array of entities
            .then(() => {})
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR SAVING:', err);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does both error happen at the same save process? Are you seeing high latency on your requests? I think this page can help troubleshoot the problem: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_an_entity

Comment: They do not happen at the exact same time but they do happen during the same process and yes, we're seeing high latency. Is there a recommended solution to slowing down the write speed? I tried writing a single entities array each time Meraki sent data rather than writing entities for each observation but I still got the same errors.

Comment: I was thinking that you're having hotspot issues because of the high latency and ingesting more data in short bursts. Could you please check if your `observationKey` is sequential? Please check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore#anti-pattern-1:-sequential-numbering-of-entity-keys) as reference.

Comment: I don't think we're setting sequential keys. We're using `const observationKey = datastore.key(type);` to generate the keys. Does this make them sequential?

Comment: Unrelated to your timeouts, but you sure your code is correct?  It looks like you push the same entity object onto the entities array for each rssi record.  This means you have X number of saves() of the same entity.

Comment: Because of the overlap in values for each observation, we just overwrite the entity's values that are different in the RSSI record during each loop. We should be appending a slightly different entity to the entities array each time. Is there a reason that overwriting values in the for loop wouldn't work?